# Import Typescript/JSX code directly from npm package

Tags: typescript, npm, webpack

I am trying to build a very basic custom npm package which will be imported in a Typescript React app (created with CRA).

React app `ALPHA`:

```
import {MyText} from 'custom-package';
function App() {
   return (
      <div>
         {MyText()}
      </div>  
  );
}
```

Now, `node_modules/custom-package` includes `package.json` and `index.ts`:

index.ts

```
export const myText=():string=>'Hello world';
```

The above code gives me the following error: `You may need an additional loader to handle the result...`

**1. Why React app is unable to parse the imported Typescript code? Why do I need to transpile it to JS?**

My thought was Webpack of ALPHA app would take over that code. Isn't it Webpack that takes over in case of '`export`' and '`import`'? For example, the following works:

index.js

```
export const myText=()=>'Hello world';
```

**2. It is Webpack that compiles 'export' in the above example. Otherwise the browser would not recognise it unless we define `<script type='module'>`. Am I right? If yes, why Webpack does not compile `index.ts` as well?**

I hope you got my point. So,

**3. Is it possible to import directly Typescript or even JSX code and how?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering each point in it's initial form:

**1. Why React app is unable to parse the imported Typescript code? Why do I need to transpile it to JS?**

Webpack has what's called a loaders chain for files; those loaders are specified in `webpack.config.js` on a subset of files, usually by extension and location in the project.

For your case `node_modules` are most likely not transpiled because:

1. not all apps use Typescript. To a large extent they don't.
2. most library authors provide a `"main"` field in their `package.json` pointing to a file that's already been transpiled prior to uploading to npm
3. `node_modules` tends to be bigger (lots bigger) than project code and it's in nobody's best interest to have webpack parse all of that with each project build.

**2. It is Webpack that compiles 'export' in the above example. Otherwise the browser would not recognise it unless we define `<script type='module'>`. Am I right? If yes, why Webpack does not compile index.ts as well?**

What webpack does (but again, depending on configuration) is it bundles all files together like this (oversimplified):

```
var files = { 
   1: () => { /* transpiled code of some file */ },  
   2: () => { var myLib = require(1); /* transpiled code of some other file */ },  
   /* ...so on */
}

var require = function(id) { return files[id]() }
```

It's clear here that `export`s no longer matter, as all code has been bundled together; webpack is otherwise likely not to parse typescript due to the reasons outlined at #1.

**3. Is it possible to import directly Typescript or even JSX code and how?**

It is possible, but it will likely slow down build speed. This can be achieved by extending the `.ts` loaders to `node_modules`, or at least `node_modules/custom-package`:

1. locate `webpack.config.js`
2. either remove `exclude: /node_modules/,` if you find any from a loaders block that deals with `ts` files, or,
3. add the same loaders to `node_modules` -

   ```
   module: {
     rules: [
       {
         test: /\.tsx?$/,
         include: /node_modules/,
         loader: 'ts-loader',
       },
     ],
   },
   ```